# ORA-01180 when restoring the database

Tags: oracle, rman

I get the following error message when trying to restore the database from backup using RMAN.

```
rman target /

RMAN> set dbid=130474031
RMAN> configure device type 'sbt_tape' clear;
RMAN> startup nomount;
RMAN> restore controlfile from autobackup;
RMAN> sql 'alter database mount';
RMAN> restore database;

Starting restore at 22-DEC-15
using channel ORA_DISK_1

creating datafile fno=1 name=/opt/oracle/oradata/prod/system01.dbf
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-03002: failure of restore command at 12/22/2015 12:47:01
ORA-01180: can not create datafile 1
ORA-01110: data file 1: '/opt/oracle/oradata/prod/system01.dbf'
RMAN>
```